# Add block on single product page

Tags: magento2, product, overrides

I'm trying to override how products are displayed adding some stuff.
I've already done with the listing page: Created new file on

```
app/code/vendor/module/Block/Product/ListProduct.php
```

`di.xml` telling to use my file and it works. Just copied the method `getProductDetailsHtml` and modified as I wanted.

But with the single product view, I don't know what I have to override, I'm searching on

```
Magento\Catalog\Block\Product
```

But I can't figure out what magento uses for display a single product. How you guys know? what methodology I need to use to figure out these things?
For example: "I need to know what magento is doing on this page". It's a nightmare for me browsing on the magento core directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To override the product single page, firstly you need to override the **catalog_product_view.xml** layout file in your **custom module or custom theme**

Try below code in **catalog_product_view.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="name_of_block_which_you_want_to_override">
                <block class="Vendorname\Module\Block\Blockanme" name="name_display" template="Vendor_Module::yourtemplate.phtml" group="pass_group_name">
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then you need to your **create your block and layout** file which you mention on above file.

After that clear the cache by running **cache:clean** command and check

Comment: Can't I do it like the same way I did with ListProduct? Just overriding a class changing the method they do for display the product?

Comment: Well yes you can do it  that way as well. You need to give preference for the same