# Hide information on single product page

Tags: magento2, product, layout, template, overrides

I'd like to hide actions block on the single product page **(only certain products):**

[image]

I thought magento managed to show this information with a single phtml so I'd overrided entirely and insert an if block to show/hide this section.

But I see it uses a lot of templates and don't know how to do it to take control on it.

I did a similar question only for add a block [Add block on single product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148349/add-block-on-single-product-page), but in this case I need to control the existing block.

I'm trying to solve the problem like @chirag said but I can't figure out why it's not working, so I'll put the names and paths:

`\app\code\GSP\Mto\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.main.title">
        <block class="GSP\Mto\Block\Product\View\MtoSingle"
               name="product.view.mto"
               template="GSP_Mto::product/view/mto_single.phtml"
               after="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceBlock name="product.info" template="GSP_Mto::product/view/form.phtml" />
</body>
</page>
```

`app\code\GSP\Mto\view\frontend\templates\product\view\form.phtml`

```
<p> test </p>
```

expected result: paragraph test instead of form qty and add to cart.

actual result: default magento template.

**UPDATE:** I'm looking around and I don't see nothing wrong, seems it has to be something about priorities. Magento just uses his template as default.
If I write

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info" template="GSP_Mto::product/view/form.phtml" remove="true" />
```

It works, the addtocart and qty disappears. But when I only indicate to use my template, magento just show it as default.

**The only way it 'works out'** is writing a line on di.xml:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" type="GSP\Mto\Block\Product\View" />
```

And copy the entire class on my module. But this is just ridiculous. **And then messies the button addtocart not showing it, seems breaks something**

It has to be a silly thing but it kept me an entirely day and I couldn't fix it.

**UPDATE2:** Tried to write directly on `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="GSP_Mto::product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
```

My template. **This is the only way that works everything** but **completely wrong** way to do it.

I think I'm going to lose my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your **condition** in three files for hiding this block.

**1. product/view/addto.phtml**

**2. product/view/mailto.phtml**

**3. product/view/form.phtml**

**[NOTE]** Copy content of this files in your custom files and then you can write your required condition.

**Your** `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info" template="{YourVendor}_{Your_Module}::product/view/form.phtml"></referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addto" template="{YourVendor}_{Your_Module}::product/view/addto.phtml"></referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" template="{YourVendor}_{Your_Module}::product/view/mailto.phtml"></referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Looks nice, I thought there will be so many blocks to override. But I have a silly problem, don't know why magento still uses his template instead of mine. If I write `<referenceBlock name="product.info.addto" remove="true" />` I see that block disappears but when I write like you did indicating my template doesn't work. Need to do anything else? Paths are correct. I tried to write: `vendor_module::product/view/form.phtml` and `vendor_module/product/view/form.phtml`

Comment: uppss, you have to use `vendor_module::product/view/form.phtml`.

Comment: I've already tried, and not working. I hate magento for this things, how I know what is happening?

Comment: Have you check the path of your template file?

Comment: Yes, also I tried to use another template that I know is working fine and nothing. There aren't something about priorities? seems it has to be that.

Comment: no, have you add your layout and template file code or path?

Comment: I updated question

Comment: have you close `</page>` tag? in your layout

Comment: Yes, forgot 4 spaces, don't know why it didn't display